# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '<' in Vue 2 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this very old application made in Vue 2 and everything was working fine but just today, I am experiencing this error: `Uncaught SystaxError:  Unexpected Token '<'`.

[image]

When I click the link, it returns an HTML file, the index file of my project:

[image]

So to check, I tried to build `npm run build` the project locally. Upon checking on the generated files, the file returns a proper script file.

[image]

I also tried to run the project on docker locally, and it was working fine. I tried the usually answer `publicPath: '/'` but it does not work on my issue.

Can somebody tell what is wrong with my project build?

Comment: Can you provide any information about what might have changed between when it was working last and now?

Comment: I just added some feature changes. No configuration changes made. After I deployed those feature changes, I encountered this error. I tried to rollback my updated but the error is still occuring.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this problem is mostly linked to your server configuration and not to your vue app.

Your app is requesting a JS file and getting back and html file.

The two most common sources would be:

- the js file requested does not exist on the server
- the webserver you're using ( nginx for example ) isn't well configured

Could you check that the server contains the js file ? if not could you share your nginx config ( or the config for the web server you're using )

Comment: this is the nginx.conf file used in this project https://pastebin.com/VV0S1r2x

Comment: You do have       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; so your config should be good, could you please make sure the file exists on your server? ( if this is inside a docker container, do run it interactively and check the files inside )

Comment: I dont have access to the server where the project is currently deployed but upon checking on my local docker, it seems that the files that cause the error do not exist.